# Morphia/MongoDB: ordering search results from advanced queries

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, full-text-search, morphia, nosql

I'm fairly new to [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), and document-oriented databases in general. I'm looking for general guidance on how to approach the following problem.

We have a DB with around 500K `Book` documents.

```
{ 
   "isbn" : "0-691-01305-5", 
   "title" : "For Whom the Bell Tolls", 
   "titleFTS" : [
       "bell",
       "toll" ],
   "author" : "Hemingway, Ernest",
   "ratingsCount" : 138, 
   "rating" : "3.5", 
   "sales" : 10245
   "price" : "12.95", 
   "category" : "fiction", 
   "description" : "The story of a young American in the International Brigades attached to a republican guerilla unit during the Spanish Civil War.",
   "descriptionFTS" : [
       "story",
       "young",
       "americ",
       "internat",
       "brigade",
       "attach",
       "republic",
       "guerilla",
       "unit",
       "spanish",
       "civil",
       "war"]
}
```

We need to perform full-text searches over the title and description fields. To that end, I have created `titleFTS` and `descriptionFTS` arrays that contains the words from the `title` and `description` fields respectively, filtered of stop words, and then stemmed.

When searching, users enter keywords, and we return the Books that match all of the entered terms, e.g.:

```
db.Book.find({ titleFTS : { $all: ['spanish', 'civil', 'war']}})
db.Book.find({ descriptionFTS : { $all: ['spanish', 'civil', 'war']}})
```

This works fine, but but now we come to the tough part: we'd like to order the results from the above queries based on multiple criteria. One such proposed ordering is the following:

1. books matching search terms in both `titleFTS` and `descriptionFTS` fields
2. books matching in only the `titleFTS` field
3. books matching in only the `descriptionFTS` field
4. books with greatest # of `sales`
5. books with highest `rating`
6. books with highest `ratingscount`

Our app is written in Java and uses the MorphiaDB API. I can envision how to write a Java [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this sort of thing pretty easily, but obviously I'd like to do to the ordering at the DB level.

Which finally brings me to the question: can this be done using the Morphia API? Or do I need to delve into writing Javascript with DB.command()? Does it require Map/Reduce? If so, a hint as to how to implement map/reduce for this problem would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend an external fulltext engine for now like Solr or ElasticSearch.
The capabilities of MongoDB related to fulltext search are truely not suitable
for a *real* fulltext solution. Your approach with pre-stemming etc. is just a dirty workaround. As long as MongoDB does not provide a suitable fulltext integration, go with an external solution if you are interested in a serious and working solution.

Comment: Hmm, I've used Lucene in the (distant) past, but didn't know about Solr. While it would handle the FTS quite nicely, do you think that Solr would also be able to handle the other types of queries I mentioned? Or would I need to keep using MongoDB (or some RDBMS) for that, in conjunction with Solr?

Comment: Lucene and Solr are basically the same. Both Solr and ElasticSearch can deal with all kind of sophistacted queries, ranking, sorting etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene and solr allow you to build complex Boolean queries on many fields including number range queries and even geodsitance queries.